# Change list-group-item from hidden to visible with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list which contains of several items that are hidden.
In my JS i want a function that changes the items of this list so it becomes visible. I want each item to become visible if a certain event has happened. The event is working fine and can be considered as shakeCount= 6, to test it properly.

Here is my list:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group">
    <div id="s1"><a href="#shake1" class="list-group-item hidden">Shake1</a></div>
    <div id="s2"><a href="#shake2" class="list-group-item hidden">Shake2</a></div>
    <div id="s3"><a href="#shake3" class="list-group-item hidden">Shake3</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i tried so far and didn't work:

```js
function nR(){
        if (shakeCount>5)
            document.getElementbyId("s1").style.visibility ="visible";
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Toggle? I would recommend it but you may need to remove the "hidden" class from your elements and add in the `style="display: none;"` attribute to each in order to default them to hidden.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group">
    <div id="s1"><a href="#shake1" class="list-group-item" style="display: none;">Shake1</a></div>
    <div id="s2"><a href="#shake2" class="list-group-item" style="display: none;">Shake2</a></div>
    <div id="s3"><a href="#shake3" class="list-group-item" style="display: none;">Shake3</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function nR(){
        if (shakeCount>5)
            document.getElementbyId("s1").toggle();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using `getElementbyId` -- it should be `getElementById` (missing capital 'B').

Second, you've made the `#shake` links `visibility:hidden`, but you are targeting the wrapping `div` when you run your js.

```js
var shakeCount = 6;

if (shakeCount>5)
            document.getElementById("s1").style.visibility ="visible";
```

```css
.hidden {visibility: hidden;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group">
    <div id="s1" class="list-group-item hidden"><a href="#shake1" >Shake1</a></div>
    <div id="s2" class="list-group-item hidden"><a href="#shake2" >Shake2</a></div>
    <div id="s3" class="list-group-item hidden"><a href="#shake3" >Shake3</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code hides the wrapping `div` elements instead of the links so that they are shown when the js runs.